# Upgrading Windows 8.1 Emedded Pro to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1

I already know that my PC is not eligible for the free Windows 10 upgrade, so I now have a windows 10 home key. What do I do next? I am assuming that there is no way to keep all my files and programs through installation, so I will be taking the ones I care about off. Is my best option to just install Windows 10 over top of my previous windows 8.1 installation, and if so, how should I do that? Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: I assume you have a Windows 10 embedded professional key?

Comment: No, Just a standard Windows 10 Home key. Sorry that I didn't mention that.

Comment: You would have to format the device to upgrade to Windows 10

Comment: How would I go about doing that? By "the device" do you mean the drive that I want to install it on?

Comment: I know zero about the device.  It might not even be compatible with Windows 10 Home.  There a reason your not upgrading it to an Embedded version of Windows 10?

Comment: I didn't know that it existed. Unlike the windows 7 computer in my house, there is no option to do so. I believe that it is not possible to update embedded versions of windows. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: The free upgrade offer only applies to consumer versions of Windows 10.  Windows 10 Embedded isn't considered to be a consumer version.  It still exists, and if purchase, you can still upgrade the installation of Windows 8.1 Embedded to Windows 10 Embedded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Backup your data you want to keep.
- Boot from the Windows 10 installer.
- During setup, Delete all existing hard drive partitions, leaving the whole drive "Unallocated".

[image]

- Hit Next, and continue on with installation as instructed by the installer.